# How can I bind parameters in a scikit-learn pipeline?

Tags: scikit-learn, keras

I have a `pipeline` object whose hyperparameters I want to optimize using a `RandomizedSearchCV`, but I need to bind two parameters, in the sense that if one is set to a value the other one is automatically set to the same value.

Here is my concrete case: I chain a PCA which reduces to `nbFeature` dimensions, to a Keras classifier which requires its input dim `nbFeature` to be explicited. Obviously this fails when the two do not match. See a toy example below:

```python
# setup
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

# toy data
n = 500
p = 100
X = np.random.normal(size=(n,p))
Y = np.concatenate((np.zeros(int(n/2)),np.ones(int(n/2))))

# toy pipeline
nbFeature = 10 # the guy to bind between the PCA and my Keras model

reducer = PCA(n_components=nbFeature)

def myBasicDense(n_feature):
    return KerasClassifier(build_fn=buildfn_myBasicDense,n_feature=n_feature,verbose=0) 
def buildfn_myBasicDense(n_feature=777):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1,input_dim=n_feature,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model  
model = myBasicDense(n_feature=nbFeature) # tried using 'reducer.n_components' but this only uses the value once, instead of binding

pipeStep = [('reducer',reducer),('model',model)]
pipe = Pipeline(pipeStep)

# run RandomizedSearchCV
# this works only when sampled 'reducer__n_components' and 'model__n_feature' are equal
gridDist = {'reducer__n_components': [10, 50],'model__n_feature': [10, 50]}

n_iter_search = 2
optimizedPipe = RandomizedSearchCV(
        refit=True,        
        estimator=pipe,
        param_distributions=gridDist,
        n_iter=n_iter_search,
        scoring='accuracy',
        cv=3,         
        verbose=2,
        random_state=12 # chosen so that is fails on second round...
        )

optimizedPipe.fit(X,Y)
```

**So here is my question**: is there a way to specify to a pipeline that two or more of its parameters must always be the same, so that I can grid search for only one of them?

(Alternatively, any workaround is welcome, including a better use of `RandomizedSearchCV`).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Combine your two steps in a wrapper which takes the parameters as input and passes them to both the steps.

Comment: Hi Vivek. Thanks, can you please elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions to your problem:

**Update**: This method only works with GridSearchCV and not RandomizedSearchCV. Please use the (2) below.

1) Group the parameters in the gridDist together.

Instead of

```
gridDist = {'reducer__n_components': [10, 50],'model__n_feature': [10, 50]}
```

you should do this:

```
gridDist = [{'reducer__n_components': [10],'model__n_feature': [10]},
            {'reducer__n_components': [50],'model__n_feature': [50]}]
```

What this does it that it makes 2 dictionaries. And the parameters inside the dictionary are always explored together. So you will always have n_components and n_feature value same. See this example for a better usage of this type of parameter grid:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-compare-reduction-py

2) Make a wrapper as I have suggested in the comment. Something like this:

```
def myBasicDense(n_feature):
    return KerasClassifier(build_fn= buildfn_myBasicDense, n_feature=n_feature, verbose=0) 
def buildfn_myBasicDense(n_feature=777):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1,input_dim=n_feature,activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

class CustomWrapper(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):

    def __init__(self, n_features=10):
        self.n_features = n_features

        # This n_features is passed to both your parts of the pipeline
        self.pipe = Pipeline([('reducer',PCA(n_components=n_features)),('model', myBasicDense(n_feature=n_features))])

    def fit(self, X, y):

        self.pipe.fit(X, y)
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        return self.pipe.predict(X)

    def set_params(self, **params):
        super(CustomWrapper, self).set_params(**params)
        self.pipe = Pipeline([('reducer',PCA(n_components=self.n_features)),('model',myBasicDense(n_feature=self.n_features))])
        return self
```

Now you have only a single hyper-parameter to search - `n_features`. So your parameter grid becomes:

```
gridDist = {'n_features': [10, 50]}
```

And you initialize the RandomSearch as follows:

```
wrapperModel = CustomWrapper()

optimizedPipe = RandomizedSearchCV(
        refit=True,        
        estimator=wrapperModel,
        param_distributions=gridDist,
        n_iter=n_iter_search,
        scoring='accuracy',
        cv=3,         
        verbose=2,
        random_state=12 # chosen so that is fails on second round...
        )
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, I thought it was ok because the CV runs without errors, but I realise after introsepection that `n_features` is actually not updated in the estimator during the CV. This is visibile if we add a `print(n_features)` in `CustomWrapper.buildfn_myBasicDense`: it remains to the default value from `__init__`. It's a bit like if `set_params` is not called properly but I don't understand why, as we use inheritance from classes `BaseEstimator` and `ClassifierMixin` (as explained in the [http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#estimators](dev doc))

Comment: @0-tree No, its not related to set_params(). Its how keras build_fn works. I have edited the code to take care of it.

Comment: Indeed seems to work now, thanks!
Not crucial but do you mind explaining why we need this extra super() call? Is this the case specifically because we use a Keras classifier here?

Comment: @0-tree No, since we are overriding the set_params() call, so we need to make sure that the original set_params() from BaseEstimator is called. And then we do the needful for the Keras by initializing the pipe again.

Comment: @0-tree For your suggested edit, I rejected it, since we are already inside the CustomWrapper, so I dont think it would be appropriate to initialize that again.

Comment: I tried that on my side and it seems to work. But I admit if this can create deeper problems I may not be aware of this, so ok ;)